# Color Listbox.Item[N] where N is generated by code

Tags: delphi

I have a Listbox.  I populate it with a file using this:

```
IF Opendialog1.Execute then
   BEGIN
      Listbox1.Items.LoadfromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
   END;
```

The file loaded contains numbers, and numbers only (I assume). 
To be 100 pct. sure, I now starts a scan:  (pseudocode :)

```
for N := 0 til Listbox1.Items.Count -1 DO
   BEGIN
      NUM := ScanForNotNumberInListbox1Item(Listbox1.Items[N]);
      // 
      // returns NUM = -1 if non digit is met..
      //    
      IF NUM <> 0 then      
         begin
            LISTBOX1.Items[N].BackGroundColor := RED;
            Exit;  (* or terminate *)
         END;
  END;
```

I know I have to use LIstbox1.DrawItem ();  and have tried several af the examples shown here in Stack Exchange, but none of the used examples seems to be code-generated.

So how Can I do that ?

Kris

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

You can store additional information about each list item in its associated "object". This can be a (pointer to a) real object, or you can use this pointer-sized integer to encode any simple information you want.

As a simple example, let's put the item's background colour in this field (`uses Math`):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListBox1.Clear;
    for i := 1 to 100 do
      ListBox1.Items.AddObject(i.ToString, TObject(IfThen(Odd(i), clSkyBlue, clMoneyGreen)));
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  ListBox: TListBox;
  Canvas: TCanvas;
  S: string;
begin
  ListBox := Control as TListBox;
  Canvas := ListBox.Canvas;

  Canvas.Brush.Color := TColor(ListBox.Items.Objects[Index]);
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  S := ListBox.Items[Index];
  Canvas.TextRect(Rect, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter]);
end;
```

Don't forget to set the list box's `Style` property to `lbOwnerDrawFixed` (say).

[image: Screenshot of a form with a list box with alternating row colours.]

A more "advanced" approach would be to associate an actual object with each item:

```
type
  TItemFormat = class
    BackgroundColor: TColor;
    TextColor: TColor;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  ItemFormat: TItemFormat;
begin

  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ListBox1.Clear;
    for i := 1 to 100 do
    begin
      ItemFormat := TItemFormat.Create;
      ItemFormat.BackgroundColor := IfThen(Odd(i), clSkyBlue, clMoneyGreen);
      ItemFormat.TextColor := IfThen(Odd(i), clNavy, clGreen);
      ListBox1.Items.AddObject(i.ToString, ItemFormat);
    end;
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  ListBox: TListBox;
  Canvas: TCanvas;
  ItemFormat: TItemFormat;
  S: string;
begin
  ListBox := Control as TListBox;
  Canvas := ListBox.Canvas;
  ItemFormat := ListBox.Items.Objects[Index] as TItemFormat;

  Canvas.Brush.Color := ItemFormat.BackgroundColor;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  S := ListBox.Items[Index];
  Canvas.Font.Color := ItemFormat.TextColor;
  Canvas.TextRect(Rect, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter]);
end;
```

[image: Screenshot of a form with a list box with alternating row colours; in this image, the text colours also alternate.]

(In this case, you own the objects, so you are responsible for freeing them when they are no longer needed.)

## Putting everything in action

In your particular case, I'd try something like

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, dummy, FirstInvalidIndex: Integer;
begin

  with TOpenDialog.Create(Self) do
    try
      Filter := 'Text files (*.txt)|*.txt';
      Options := [ofPathMustExist, ofFileMustExist];
      if Execute then
        ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    finally
      Free;
    end;

  FirstInvalidIndex := -1;
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := 0 to ListBox1.Count - 1 do
      if not TryStrToInt(ListBox1.Items[i], dummy) then
      begin
        ListBox1.Items.Objects[i] := TObject(1);
        if FirstInvalidIndex = -1 then
          FirstInvalidIndex := i;
      end;
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;

  if FirstInvalidIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    ListBox1.ItemIndex := FirstInvalidIndex;
    MessageBox(Handle, 'An invalid row was found.', PChar(Caption), MB_ICONERROR);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  ListBox: TListBox;
  Canvas: TCanvas;
  S: string;
begin
  ListBox := Control as TListBox;
  Canvas := ListBox.Canvas;

  Canvas.Font.Assign(ListBox.Font);

  if odSelected in State then
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
    Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
  end
  else
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clWindow;
    Canvas.Font.Color := clWindowText;
  end;

  if ListBox.Items.Objects[Index] = TObject(1) then
  begin
    Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
    Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold, fsStrikeOut]
  end;

  Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  S := ListBox.Items[Index];
  Canvas.TextRect(Rect, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter]);

end;
```

[image: A form with a list box containing numbers and the occasional non-numeric row. The non-numeric rows are highlighted in red and strike through.]

*The fine print:* Notice that the above snippets are only simple examples intended to demonstrate the basic approach. In a real application, you need to be more careful about the details. For instance, you cannot use a hard-coded red text colour if the background colour is a system colour (because that colour might very well be red too!).

In addition, what happens if the text file is empty (try it!)?

Comment: #Andreas Rejbrand: You're Right. You got a point there. But in my real code (not the pseudo code I presented) I do check for empty lines.  I wanted the question to be as sahort as possible., so I omitted a lot of checks  (try  - except - finally - as one of them).

Comment: I have been out of town, so I could not check/try the code. I'll do that later to day, and I will be back later. Anyway thanks a lot for the code and the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Set `lbOwnerDrawFixed` (or another ownerdraw) style for Listbox

Listbox items have auxiliary property  `Objects[]` and you can set `Objects[i]` to non-nil value for invalid items

```
IF NUM <> 0 then      
    LISTBOX1.Objects[N] := TObject(1);
```

Use some example for `OnDrawItem` event treatment and use `Objects[]` to define background color during drawing